# Splunk : Join two indexes based on substring match

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am struggling with joining two indexes based on substring match.

I have following indexes :

```
index1 :
having following fields

PROTOCOL,DIRECTION,FILENAME,DIRECTORYNAME



index2:

having following fields
APPID,CUSTOMERID,FILEPATTERN,DIRECTORYNAME
```

I want to join above indexes based on following condition

1. FILEPATTERN is substring of FILENAME
2. DIRECTORYNAME in index1 = DIRECTORYNAME in index 2.

and display output with following fields

```
PROTOCOL,DIRECTION,APPID,CUSTOMERID,FILEPATTERN,DIRECTORYNAME
```

Thanks in anticipation

Regards

Nikhil

Answer (score 2):

Start by using the `stats` command to merge the two indexes.

```
index=index1 OR index=index2
| stats values(*) as * by DIRECTORYNAME
```

That should produce results with fields `DIRECTORYNAME`, `APPID`, `CUSTOMERID`, `DIRECTION`, `FILENAME`, `FILEPATTERN`, `PROTOCOL`.

Then you can filter based on the relationship between `FILENAME` and `FILEPATTERN`:

```
| where match(FILENAME, FILEPATTERN)
```

Comment: is stats a better use than join?

Comment: Yes!  The `join` command is quite inefficient and is subject to limits in the number of results it can handle.

Comment: @RichG
 
Thanks for the reply.
 In my case DIRECTORYNAME in index2 is DIR_NAME. Whenever i am trying to rename DIR_NAME to DIRECTORYNAME  , its overwriting all the values in other index.

Comment: I like to use `coalesce` in those conditions.  It's output is the first non-null argument.  `index=index1 OR index=index2 | eval dir=coalesce(DIRECTORYNAME, DIR_NAME) | stats values(*) as * by dir`.

Comment: you *likely* need to split-back-out the `FILENAME` and `FILEPATTERN` fields - because you cannot `macth` multivalue-to-multivalue in a reliable fashion